# InnoDB Error on MySQL Startup

Tags: mysql, innodb

When launching MySQL, I get the following InnoDB errors.

```
mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

[Warning] '--skip-locking' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--skip-external-locking' instead.

[Warning] 'record_buffer' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use 'read_buffer_size' instead.

[Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M

InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 503316480 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!

[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.

[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

[Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events


[Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 12485  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

[Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown
```

The contents of `my.conf` is:

```
[mysqld]

 local-infile=0

 port = 12485

#skip-innodb

#socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

#innodb_log_file_size=503316480

#innodb_force_recovery=6

skip-locking

query_cache_limit=1M

query_cache_size=4M

query_cache_type=1

max_allowed_packet=800M

max_connections=2000

interactive_timeout=1000

wait_timeout=1000

connect_timeout=100

thread_cache_size=8

key_buffer=8M

join_buffer=1M

table_cache=100

record_buffer=1M

sort_buffer_size=2M

read_buffer_size=2M

max_connect_errors=200

thread_concurrency=1

myisam_sort_buffer_size=4M

server-id=1

[safe_mysqld]

err-log=/var/log/mysqld.log

open_files_limit=400

[mysqldump]

quick

[mysql]

#default-storage-engine=myisam

no-auto-rehash

#safe-updates

[isamchk]

key_buffer=4M

sort_buffer=4M

read_buffer=4M

write_buffer=4M

[myisamchk]

key_buffer=4M

sort_buffer=4M

read_buffer=4M

write_buffer=4M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't start because you changed the size of your innodb log file size (or in this case; you commented it and MySQL is using the default now).

```
log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 503316480 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
```

If you have data in your MySQL database, I suggest you put back the innodb log file size value to its original value by removing the hash mark:

```
innodb_log_file_size=503316480
```

Also, if you're really interested in changing this setting; know that it is tricky as you might lose data in the end.
If you really need to change this setting, follow this guide on MySQL.com: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html

Comment: i hame more than 200 sql database. please explain more

Comment: please help about that I was really miserable

Comment: MySQL will not let you chang that setting on the fly for data integrity reasons. you won't lose any data if you restore the innodb_log_file_size setting to its original value.

Comment: now i have another problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510472/mysql-continuously-restart-centos

Comment: Reading the question - you probably had a crash or a hardware failure. Unfortunately I have never attempted InnoDB recovery. I just know that it is manual and you need to re-create every corrupt table. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html